# Converting latitude in decimal degrees format to a hexadecimal value

Tags: c#, type-conversion, hex, decimal, latitude-longitude

I have a latitude value in decimal degrees format (32.60601045). How would I go about converting it to a hexadecimal string?

I have a C# program that reads a hex string and decodes it into different fields. I know there is a latitude somewhere in the string whose value translates to 32.60601045, so I would like to convert the expected value of 32.60601045 into a hex string so I can locate it within my hexadecimal byte string.

**EDIT:**
Here is an example hex string:

```
02-00-62-E4-1B-C0-91-4D  40-40-AF-2D-29-64-D4-4A
5D-C0-00-66-66-6A-42-00  29-5C-8F-BD-00-00-63-00
```

Comment: What are examples of "hex strings" that contain latitudes as you describe?

Comment: I've edited the post to include an example hex string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third to tenth hexadecimal pairs in your example contain the latitude in IEEE 754 format. It can be converted to `double` as follows:

```
long val=0x40404d91c01be462L;
double dbl=BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(val);
Console.WriteLine(dbl);
```

The latitude can be converted back to its "raw" bits as follows:

```
long latBits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(dbl);
```